# Get all values from an Object who's key ends with a particular pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to retrieve all the key values from an Object, where key name ends with (say _abc).

**My Try**

```
obj = {p1_abc: 1, p2_abc: 2, p3_def: 3, p4_abc: 4, p5_def: 5}

required_keys = jQuery.map(Object.keys(obj), function(val, i){
  if(val.indexOf("_abc") != -1)
    return val;
});
//required_keys = ['p1_abc', 'p2_abc', 'p4_abc']

required_values = jQuery.map(required_keys, function(v, i){
  return(obj[v]);
});
//required_values = [1, 2, 4]
```

Here, **required_values** contains the values I require, but I feel this entire code a bit ugly. Is there a clean way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in one `.map()`

```js
obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
}

required_keys = jQuery.map(Object.keys(obj), function(val, i) {
  if (val.indexOf("_abc") != -1) {
    return obj[val];
  }

});
document.write(required_keys);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or If you want key/values you can do like

```js
obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
}

required_keys = jQuery.map(Object.keys(obj), function(val, i) {
  if (val.indexOf("_abc") != -1) {
    return {[val]:obj[val]};
  }

});
document.write(JSON.stringify(required_keys));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Both of these solutions will also match `_abc` anywhere in the string and not just at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Had a few minutes spare and this seems like a good question to introduce [`iterators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

The following is an example written in ES5, but it will also work in ES3 with the shims loaded.

```js
function makeEntriesIterator(object) {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);
  var nextKey = 0;
  return {
    next: function next() {
      if (nextKey < keys.length) {
        var key = keys[nextKey];
        var iterator = {
          value: [key, object[key]],
          done: false
        };
        nextKey += 1;
        return iterator;
      }
      return {
        value: undefined,
        done: true
      };
    }
  };
}

var obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
};

var iterator = makeEntriesIterator(obj);
var next = iterator.next();
var matches = [];
while (!next.done) {
  if (next.value[0].slice(-4) === '_abc') {
    matches.push(next.value);
  }
  next = iterator.next();
}
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(matches, null, 2);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```

In ES6, you can use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and arrays have iterators [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values), [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) and [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys), the default [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/%40%40iterator) is `values`.

```js
'use strict';

const obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
};

const matches = [];
for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (key.endsWith('_abc')) {
    matches.push([key, obj[key]]);
  }
}
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(matches, null, 2);
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.0/es6-shim.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

ES7 will introduce iterators for objects, for example [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then things become even cleaner, as you will not need to use `Object.keys`. But this can't be demonstrated just now.

```
'use strict';

const obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
};

const matches = [];
for (let [key, value] of obj) {
  if (key.endsWith('_abc')) {
    matches.push([key, value]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `.endsWith()` a native method ?

Comment: Yes, in ES6 onwards.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Answer (score 3):

First get all properties from the object with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then filter the array with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the wanted properties and finally gather all values from the object with the bracket operator for objects and return it with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a nice array.

```js
var obj = { p1_abc: 1, p2_abc: 2, p3_def: 3, p4_abc: 4, p5_def: 5, _abcp6: 6 },
    required_values = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (a) {
        return /_abc$/.test(a);
    }).map(function (a) {
        return obj[a];
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(required_values, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Another that matches `_abc` anywhere in the string and not just at the end.

Answer (score 2):

you should use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to filter and reduce items at the same time

```js
var obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
}
var regex = /_abc$/;
var required_values = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(sum, key) {
  if (regex.test(key)) {
    sum.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return sum;
}, []);

console.log(required_values);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: In pure ES5, `reduce` is the best way to solve this, rather than a combination of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: This will match `_abc` any where is the string and not just at the end.

Comment: @Xotic750 fixed that, initially wanted to do it with regex

Answer (score 1):

Try using `for..in` loop , `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` `/_abc$/` to match properties of object that end with `"_abc"`

```js
var obj = {
  p1_abc: 1,
  p2_abc: 2,
  p3_def: 3,
  p4_abc: 4,
  p5_def: 5
};

for (prop in obj) {
  if (/_abc$/.test(prop))
    console.log(obj[prop]) // do stuff with `prop` , `obj[prop]`
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the OP said `where key name ends with (say _abc)`, but the RegExp currently used will test for `_abc` anywhere within the string.

Comment: @Xotic750 _"Worth noting that the OP said where key name ends with (say _abc), but the RegExp currently used will test for _abc anywhere within the string. "_ Good catch. Could adjust `RegExp` to `/_abc$/`

Comment: Yes that would fix it. ;)

Comment: A nice and simple ES3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

While you tagged Jquery .. you can use `$.each()`

```
var obj = {p1_abc: 1, p2_abc: 2, p3_def: 3, p4_abc: 4, p5_def: 5}
$.each(obj , function(k , v){
  if (k.indexOf("_abc") != -1){
        alert(v)
  };
})
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/s0kfrwvm/1/)

to return array

```
var obj = {p1_abc: 1, p2_abc: 2, p3_def: 3, p4_abc: 4, p5_def: 5}
var requireKeys = [];
$.each(obj , function(k , v){
  if (k.indexOf("_abc") != -1){
      requireKeys.push(v);
  };
})
alert(requireKeys);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/s0kfrwvm/3/)

Comment: These also match `_abc` anywhere in the string and not just at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large dataset, I'd favor "performant" over "clean". This isn't the "cleanest" code, but it will be more performant than any of the other solutions (so far).

```
function getValues (obj) {
  var values = []
  for(var key in obj){
    if (key.substr(key.length - 4) === '_abc') {
      values.push(obj[key])
    }
  }
  return values
}
```

Comment: This one matches `abc` at the end of the string, which could be `_abc` but could also be `xabc`.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is `findKey` function implementation.

It returns the key of the first element predicate returns truthy for instead of the element itself.

```js
/**
 * @param {Object} collection The collection to inspect.
 * @param {Function} predicate The function.
 * @returns {*} Returns the key, else `undefined`. 
 */
var findKey = function(object, predicate) {
  let result;
  if (object == null) {
    return result;
  }
  Object.keys(object).some(function(key) {
    const value = object[key]
    if (predicate(value, key, object)) {
      result = key;
      return true;
    }
  })
  return result;
}
```

### Usage

```js
//Example usage
var collections = {
  brand_category_3320: 1133,
  brand_category_3321: 2245
};

var r = findKey(collections, function(o, key, context) {
  if (key.indexOf(3320) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log('The r is =', r);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    obj = {
      p1_abc: 1,
      p2_abc: 2,
      p3_def: 3,
      p4_abc: 4,
      p5_def: 5
    }

    required_data = Object.keys(obj).map(function(val, i) {
      if (val.indexOf("_abc") != -1)
        return {
          [val]: obj[val]
        };
    });

    console.log(required_data);
```

Will result in a new array of the reuired objects, plus you can remove jQuery.

Comment: Worth noting that this will return an array of the same length as `Object.keys`, but the unwanted data will be `undefined`. So you may need to run this through `filter` before it is usable in your programme.

Comment: Also matches `_abc` anywhere in the string and not just at the end.